# Fail to start mongod service but mongodb service

Tags: 14.04, upstart, mongodb

Ubuntu: 14.04

MongodB version: 3.2.6

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6 connecting to: test

2017-06-26T07:46:48.195+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2017-06-26T07:46:48.196+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14 
@(connect):1:6 exception: connect failed
```

Hi guys,

Our service contains both mongodb and mongod service.  We used to run mongod service (sudo service mongod start) however recently when re run mongod service, we got the error above.

However this problem didn't happen when we run mongodB service .

This is the mongod.conf file.  Wonder who can give me some advice?  Thanks!

```
storage:
  smallFiles: true
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: [127.0.0.1,X.X.X.X]

replSet=spof
replication:
        replSetName: rs0
```

Answer (score 3):

It might be due to permission issues with your db directory (dbPath). You can try giving appropriate permission to your directory. Try the following steps:

1. Give permission to `/var/lib/mongodb` directory.

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 0777 /var/lib/mongodb
   ```
2. Try to start mongod service.

   ```
   sudo service mongod start
   ```
3. Check status of mongod service.

   ```
   sudo service mongod status
   ```

Comment: changing permissions isn't correct , want to change owner to be mongodb user

Comment: seems worked for me, but the directory has to be the one that's defined in by mongod.conf for the db

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo mongod --repair
sudo service mongod start
sudo service mongod status
```

Double check you've not got conflicting rules in iptables.

Double check `/etc/mongod.conf` and check `bind_ip = 0.0.0.0` to allow external connections.

Answer (score 1):

Check logs:

```
cat /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

if you know the connection command try it:

```
mongo "mongodb://localhost/graylog"
```

If you see a core dump from this command (as root) look into changing permissions on /var/lib/mongodb  ( change recursive ownership to mongodb:mongodb )

```
/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed by **backup** and completely removing Mongo data directory (in my case `/var/lib/mongodb/`).  And after that, recreate database path using :

`sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb/`

`sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/`

This guy solved it: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/252393/162290

Answer (score -1):

You may try the following:

1. remove the .lock file.
   sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
2. grant the permission 
   sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
3. restart server
   sudo service mongod start

Answer (score -2):

The format of `bindIp` is not correct.

If you want to have multiple IPs, you should do it like this:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,X.X.X.X
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! Looks like the correct format is indeed what the OP has: `bindIp = [127.0.0.1, 192.168.0.155, 10.0.0.155]`. You might want to edit the answer.